# Return method return several times

Tags: java, loops, return

I want to make a method return that return several times a String from a list of String. any idea ??

Comment: Please show us your code, your input, and expected output.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: my input is a list of string and my output will be a string from this list

Comment: don't just describe your input and code, paste it here as is. Also, your question is not readable. Try to make it clear. We cannot help you, if we don't understand the problem

Comment: Are u trying to join string in the list?

Comment: `return list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()));`

Comment: @SteveSmith +1 for getting the question. Put it in a loop and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
String getRandomString(List<String> list) {
    return list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()));
}
```

This isn't the most efficient way, but should do the job.

Comment: this method return a random String , i want it to return the selected String from the list

Comment: Change it to `return list.get(idx);`

Comment: is there a similar method like : return list.getselectedItem(); i don't want to add parameter

Comment: How will it know which item is selected?  Are you talking about a GUI dropdown list?

Comment: yes, i want a method like list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()));
but return selected item not a random one